# How to operate on an ajax requested set of elements

Tags: jquery, django

i'm currently working in a web app and i'm using django-jquery, and when i load a set of elements via jQuery's .load() method i need to add functionality to the new set of elemnts but it looks like the existing code doesn't work on it, i think that i need to reload the dom tree, or use somthing like $.getScript after calling .load()

my first question is: in your opinion what is the best way to acomplish this task.

second: django encourages not to use querystrings, how much of this philosophy is practical in real world.

any comment on any of this topics is welcome.

Comment: "Citation Needed" for "django encourages not to use querystrings". Where did you read that? It's easy to abuse them but they have their use - 'query'ing things. I'd use them for search queries - /foo/bar/search?term=foo&type=bar, for example. Don't leverage them as part of a URL scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing code does not work on the new elements loaded from the jQuery's .load() function because the functions are not bound to the new elements. So use [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/) `.live()` function.

> **Description**: Attach an event handler for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now and **in the future**.

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or later, `.live` is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: Tanks it was very helpfull. Unfotunately i can't vote positive i'd love to.

Comment: i need 15 but tanks anyway, i'll do better the next time